# re.sub, regex and exact matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match any instances of '1c' in a text file and replace them using re in Python. I've tried many different combinations using positive lookahead, but still no success. It would be great if anyone better than me with Regex could point me in the right direction.

Here's my script:

```
import re

with open('lorem.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(re.sub("1(?=c)", "</h1>", data))
```

And the text file:

```
Lorem hello dolor sit amet, 
1consetetur sadipscing elitr 1c, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem hello dolor sit amet. Lorem hello dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem hello dolor sit amet. Lorem hello dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem hello dolor sit amet.
```

I **only** want to match the 1c, not the 1, and replace it with a closed h1 tag.

Thus far I've tried amongst others:

```
"1\(?=c\)"
"1/(?=c)"
"1$(?=c)"
"^(1c)$"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace 1c in `1consetetur` as well?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I ultimately want to replace en masse, and as far as I understand it using re.sub is a more efficient way of doing it. I also want to know how to do the regex personally...thanks

Comment: Why not `\b1c\b`? https://regex101.com/r/4H1G4s/1/

Comment: If you need  a whole word regex, it is a mere `re.sub(r"\b1c\b", "</h1>", data)`. Whole word matching is  a very well-known problem.

Comment: @mrzasa no that one I want to avoid - so only the 1c that exists by itself

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks Wiktor I'll try that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew worked! thank you - how do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: No need to, the question has been answered many times.

Comment: ah well I looked a lot, clearly in the wrong places :)